# How to Cleanly shutdown database in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to import some database at my neo4j local server. I unpacked data from archive do data/databases change active.db and allow_format_migration had changed to true.
But now when I use bin/neo4j start I had error in log/neo4j. There are many lines but I think problem is with it:

```
Please see the attached cause exception "The database is not cleanly shutdown. The database needs recovery, in order to recover the database, please run the old version of the database on this store.".
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've read ton's of information and found the answer.
Just need to delete transaction files inside your database folder and run neo4j.

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade from 3.5.6 to 4.2.7 and I have deleted 2 separate neostore.transaction.db.XX files found in my neo4j-community-xxx > data > databases > [dbname] folder, but I am still receiving the same error about 'not cleanly shutdown'.
Any idea what else I need to do for a clean shutdown?